# Any Missing code in my Make file

Tags: c, compiler-errors, gnu-make

i wrote a makefile with some commands.after running command `make` got a errors `undefined reference to sqrt`and `undefined reference to exp`
my make file :

```
CFILES = smLe.c iniTra.c le.c res.c uti.c smClass.c   ini.c clas.c 
OBJECTS = smLe.o iniTra.o le.o res.o uti.o smClass.o ini.o clas.o
OBJECTS1 = smLe.o iniTra.o le.o res.o uti.o
OBJECTS2 = smClass.o ini.o clas.o 
CFLAGS = -O -lm
CC = gcc

.c .o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -c $<

p1: $(OBJECTS1)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS1) -o $@

p2: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS2) -o $@

smLe.o: iniTra.h le.h res.h
iniTra.o: iniTra.h
le.o: iniTra.h uti.h le.h
res.o: iniTra.h le.h res.h
smClass.o: ini.h clas.h
ini.o: ini.h clas.h
clas.o: ini.h clas.h
```

Is it any thing missing in my make file.why this error occur in this make file code?please help me ..thanks

Answer (score 1):

-lm is an LDLIB, you pass it to the linker

```
CFLAGS = -O 
LDLIBS = -lm
CC = gcc

.c .o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -c $<

p1: $(OBJECTS1)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS1) -o $@  $(LDLIBS)
```

Libraries have to appear after object files that call what is in them on the command line.

Comment: @user39133 I think that should do it, p2 would be comparable.

Comment: +1. `LDLIBS` is the standard place where libraries go. OP should try to use [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules) when posible.

Comment: got one executable p1 but don't get p2 ..why ?

Comment: @user39133 did you change p2 to look like p1 in the answer?

Comment: @user39133 not sure then, what's the error message?